# sort columns values in pandas to create alternate sequence

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create an alternate order for my dataframe based on the last character of a string.

Here is an example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ('2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-02'),
                  'Account': ('123A', '123B', '456A', '456A', '456B', '456B'),
                  'Type': ('1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2')})

df = df.sort_values(['Date', 'Type'])
df
         Date Account Type
0  2019-01-01    123A    1
1  2019-01-01    123B    1
2  2019-01-02    456A    2
3  2019-01-02    456A    2
4  2019-01-02    456B    2
5  2019-01-02    456B    2
```

The output I want is:

```
         Date Account Type
0  2019-01-01    123A    1
1  2019-01-01    123B    1
2  2019-01-02    456A    2
4  2019-01-02    456B    2
3  2019-01-02    456A    2
5  2019-01-02    456B    2
```

If you look at line 2 and 4 you can see that the last character of the sting has been alternate. So basically, I would like to sort by Date, Type and df['Account'].str[-1:] where df['Account'].str[-1:] is always alternate A-B, A-B for the same root in the account.

I have tried to create new columns to identify problematic rows, but don't know how to reorder.

```
df['test1'] = np.where((df['Account'].str[:3].shift(-1) == df['Account'].str[:3]) & (df['Account'].str[-1:].shift(-1) == 'B') & (df['Account'].str[-1:] == 'B'), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby(['Date','Type', 'Account']).cumcount()
df.sort_values(['Date', 'Type', 'rank'])
```

Output:

```
+----+---------------------+-----------+--------+--------+
|    | Date                | Account   |   Type |   rank |
|----+---------------------+-----------+--------+--------|
|  0 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 123A      |      1 |      0 |
|  1 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 123B      |      1 |      0 |
|  2 | 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 456A      |      2 |      0 |
|  4 | 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 456B      |      2 |      0 |
|  3 | 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 456A      |      2 |      1 |
|  5 | 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 456B      |      2 |      1 |
+----+---------------------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: How about drop the columns at the end ?